# Twitter bootstrap always visible footer

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I need to create a footer which is always visible ? I am using twitter bootstrap.
When the content gets lengtheir, I have to scroll down to see the footer, is there a way to always show the footer ?

Answer (score 10):

If you are using Bootstrap 3.0 you can add a simple Nav-Class.

The Footer is always fixed to bottom and is always visible.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">
    <!-- Your Footer Content -->
</nav>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#navbar-fixed-bottom

Comment: This is an alternate solution - because you're not using the actual .footer class.

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap 3.0 you can do:

```
  <body>
    <div id="wrap">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="page-header">
          <h1>Sticky footer</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <p class="text-muted credit">Example courtesy <a href="http://martinbean.co.uk">Martin Bean</a> and <a href="http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/">Ryan Fait</a>.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

and in your CSS:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  /* The html and body elements cannot have any padding or margin. */
}

/* Wrapper for page content to push down footer */
#wrap {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: auto !important;
  height: 100%;
  /* Negative indent footer by its height */
  margin: 0 auto -60px;
  /* Pad bottom by footer height */
  padding: 0 0 60px;
}

/* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
#footer {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

Comment: This solution is for "sticky footer". Always-showing footer is a different concept.